# Performance of BinaryFormatter degrades in 64 bit application

Tags: c#, performance, binaryformatter

I am migrating a 32 bit application to a 64 bit application. With profiling I found out that in the 64 bit environment the `BinaryFormatter` suffers an immense performance hit.

**Q1** What is the reason for this massive performance degradation in the first place?

**Q2** How can I circumvent this problem?

---

#### Edit

```
public override T Load<T>(string blobName)
{
    T result = default(T);

    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(blobName))
    {
        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            result = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

            stopWatch.Stop();
            Trace.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Edit1

A complex object-network is serialized where the final stream has a length of ~3 MB.

**Profiling results:**

- 32 bit - 1,382 ms on average
- 64 bit - 13,214 ms on average

Comment: Maybe you could include your profiling code and results?

Comment: What version of .NET are you testing on?

Comment: @juharr I simply use `Stopwatch`es.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot I use .NET 4.6

Comment: @participant That's nice, but we cannot verify that your tests are correct, or try them out ourselves if you don't post the code.

Comment: It is also important to know your platform target. Btw, if performance matters, `BinaryFormatter` is not the greatest choice.

Comment: @DirkVollmar Platform target is x64.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from writing your own serializer.  Then you would have more control over how it performs.

Comment: Providing more information about the type(s) that you're running through the BinaryFormatter could be helpful.

Comment: Code on a modern processor, especially the kind that is just-in-time compiled, compares somewhat to a freight train that's half a mile long.  It needs time to get up to speed.  You never want to measure how long it takes to get going.  That measurement is spoiled by a *lot* of inevitable overhead that has nothing to do with the code.  Take the **second** measurement, never the first.  Best profiling strategy is to run the test at least 10 times at take the median value as the reliable and reproducible value.

Comment: @HansPassant I've averaged over about 280 samples.

Comment: Well, so much for the easy explanation.  Odds you'll get a good answer are slim-to-none unless you provide repro code without the "complex object-network" sting.